# Knn algorithm how it works

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, knn

When I started to understand this algorithm, I didn't quite understand how it should work. I have a dataset, and I have new data that needs to be classified.
dataset:

```
2   2   a
3   5   a
1   8   b
3   16  b
4   12  a
5   20  a
```

And a new data:

```
1   2
```

now I need to classify the new set as "a" or "b".
I can calculate distance for each set.`sqrt((aNew-Ai)^2+(bNew-Bi)^2)` for each dataset.
with distanse i have that data:

```
    a   b   dist    class
new 1   2   ?       ?
old 2   2   1,0     a
old 3   5   5,8     a
old 1   8   8,1     b
old 3   16  16,3    b
old 4   12  12,6    a
old 5   20  20,6    a
```

And for ex. K equal 6.
How should i classify  my new data?

Comment: You calculate the `k` nearest neighbors, and then the classification result is the class that occurs the most often among those `k` known instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the distance between the new data point and all the points in your dataset.

1. Arrange these distances in ascending order.
2. Pick up the first K number of distances from the list.
3. Get the class from the picked distance.
4. Now check which class has the largest repetitions or votes.

For implementation in Java refer [here](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/java-algorithms-the-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-4faca7ad26b2)

Answer (score 1):

In your example it's `a`, because is the most common value in the k (6) nearest neighbour list.
But K should be an uneven number to prevent ambiguous classification.